# How to change dur attribute in <animateMotion>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Depending on the current time I need to place a ball at a position on a line. Think of using  to position a minute hand on a clock.

I have searched the Mozilla site for `getElementbyId` documentation to see if there were attributes like "animationdelay". I tried reading in the attribute of the animateMotion id with `getElementbyId`.

```
<svg class="progress" height="500" width="500" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">


<path id="link"  d=" M 50,50 L 500,100 " fill="none"/>
<circle cx="" cy="" r=5>
<!-- Define the motion path animation -->
<animateMotion id="alterid" dur="21s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
keyPoints=".7;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
<mpath xlink:href="#link"/>
</animateMotion>
</circle>
</svg> 


x1=document.getElementById("alterid");
x1.dur="222s";
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydKjgL#anon-login

In the above code, I expect the ball animation to take 222 seconds because of the x1.dur code, instead the animation takes 21 seconds; i.e. the duration remains unchanged. How can I change the duration dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DOM elements easily using D3.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
d3.select("animateMotion")
.attr("dur", '222s')
</script>
```